# isUnique Validation in CakePHP hasMany association

Tags: cakephp

**Database Structure**

I have two tables, *users* and *nicks*.
In *users* table I have a field *username* and in *nicks* table I have a field *nick_name*

There is a *hasMany* association between *users* and *nicks*

```
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Nick' => array(
            'className' => 'Nick',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true
        )

    );
```

In the *User* model I am validating to allow only unique *username* during registration by

```
            'username must be unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'username is already taken'

            )
```

but I also don't want to allow users to register any previously used nick names as their username. for that.

```
            'somebody use that name as a nickname' => array(
                'rule' => 'checkNickName',
                'message' => 'That name is already in use'
            )
```

and

```
    public function checkNickName(){
        $nick2 = $this->find('all');
        $nickNames = array();
        foreach($nick2 as $name2){
            foreach($name2['Nick'] as $name1){
                array_push($nickNames,strtolower($name1['nick_name']));
            }

        }

        $username = strtolower($this->data['User']['username']);
        return in_array($username,$nickNames);

    }
```

But that's not working. What should I to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the nicknames.

```
$nick2 = $this->Nick->find('all');
```

Then the result array will be

```
nick2 = array(
    0    => array(                       //first foreach
        'Nick' => array(
             nickname => 'TEST'
             )
         )
     )
```

so remove the second foreach and save the value as using `$name2['Nick']['nickname']`

```
public function checkNickName(){
    $nick2 = $this->Nick->find('all');
    $nickNames = array();
    foreach($nick2 as $name2){
         array_push($nickNames,strtolower($name2['Nick']['nick_name']));
    }

    $username = strtolower($this->data['User']['username']);
    return in_array($username,$nickNames);

}
```

Comment: there are more than one users and for each user there is a field Nick and inside nick there are many nick_names

Comment: OMG, i was so silly. My original code was working. But I was editing files on my locally hosted website and I was testing the change on my live website hosted on my server. But your code works too. :)

Comment: This seems a bit excessive to check if the username exists as a nickname. When your user base grows and you have maybe 10,000 to 100,000 nicknames, you may suffer some performance issues with this code.

Comment: Check my answer for a more simple solution.

Comment: @HelloSpeakman yea it is a bit excessive. I just corrected the first code posted on the question. Your answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to ensure the username is unique but also that the username has not been used as a nickname by anybody also, so why not use something like this?

```
public function checkNickIsUnique($check = array()) {
    $value = array_values($check);

    $nicknameExists = $this->Nick->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Nick.nick_name' => $value[0]
        )
    ));

    return ($nicknameExists > 0) ? false : true;
}
```

And in your user model, assuming it's directly related to nick, have this in the validation.

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'That username has already been taken'
        ),
        'checkNickIsUnique' => array(
            'rule' => array('checkNickIsUnique'),
            'message' => 'Your username has already been taken as a nickname'
        )
    ),
);
```

All it's doing is passing the value from the validation to the method, and checking if that value exists as a nickname within the nicks table, if it does it fails validation otherwise it passes.

Answer (score 0):

just need use the username of the input form.
in your view example:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
                              'label' => array(
                                'text' => 'Provide your username'
                              )
                              )); ?>
```

and in your model you need change

```
      'username' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'not empty please',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule'    => array('isUniqueUsername'),
            'message' => 'username is already taken'
        ),
       ),


        'nickname' => array(
           'nonEmpty' => array(
              'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
              'message' => 'not empty',
              'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
           'unique' => array(
              'rule'    => array('checkNickName'),
              'message' => 'That name is already in use'
            )
        )
```

your condition example for is validation is unique user name, use this:

**EDIT**

```
  'username' => array(
    'unique' => array(
        'rule'    => array('checkNickName'),
        'message' => 'username is already taken'
    ),
   ),
```

in your function:

```
public function checkNickName($check) {
  $this->loadModel('Nick');
  $username = $this->Nick->find(
      'first',
      array(
          'fields' => array(
              'Nick.id',
              'Nick.nickname'
          ),
          'conditions' => array(
              'Nick.nickname' => $check['username']
          )
      )
  );

  if(!empty($username)){
      if($this->data[$this->alias]['id'] == $username['User']['id']){
          return true;
      }else{
          return false;
      }
  }else{
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This checks the uniqueness of username. And I'm able to do that easily by `'rule' => 'isUnique'` 
What I want is that username should be equal to any nickname. And there is no field like 'nickname' in the form. In the form I have just one field i.e username and the username should be equal to previously used username and previously used nickname.

Comment: understand nickname == username  <= this is what you need to do, is not it ?.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution that doesn't require tons of additional code is this:

```
        $valid = $this->User->saveAll($this->request->data, array(
            'atomic' => false,
            'validate' => 'only'
        ));
        debug($valid);
```

It will validate the record and all other records attached to it as well, no more code required, just make sure you have the isUnique rule in your associated nicknames model. It will as well invalidate the correct fields in your form.

Comment: OP wants to ensure that User.username has not been used in any Nick record (Nick.nick_name), you will still need a validation rule for this.